# Highcharts export - Where is the index-utf8-encode.php file

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts in many projects. When I configure exporting option, I always use "index-utf8-encode.php" because it support other charset than UTF-8 (ex: ISO-8859-1).

```
 exporting: {
    url: 'http://export.highcharts.com/index-utf8-encode.php'
}
```

Unfortunately, since weeks or months (not sure exactly when) when I try to export graph to an image file I get a 404 error from a tomcat server.

See (and try to export as image file) : http://jsfiddle.net/yWLwx/126/

So, is there someone who knows where is the index-utf8-encode.php file or why it doesn't work anymore?

Thank you very much for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Please familiar with our php exporting servers https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/php

It is caused by changing export server.

Comment: So I understand that this functionality is no longer available on the  highchart Web server. And the only way to avoid encoding problem when exporting as image is to deploy my own exporting server (or java code in the application). Did I understand well?